# Missing file extension on download from header

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-headers

i'm using the below code to download a file, which work's  well but the problem is that the file extension  is missing, even after stressful download . i have tried changing it to other MIME types, what could be the problem and how do i solve it ?

```
header('Content-Type: audio/mp3');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$row[3]");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize("$row[1]$row[2]"));
$fp = fopen("$row[1]$row[2]", "r");
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

NOTE: the values in the $row array are fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark here, could it be that the filename has a space in it? In that case you can try to add double quotes around the filename, there are reports about parts after a space being omitted (e.g. here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Filenames_with_spaces_are_truncated_upon_download)

Edit: As discussed in the comments, the headers did not return the extension, so adding the .mp3 extension manually in the back-end solves this problem.

Comment: the whole name is loaded, with spaces eg "my new mix" missing the ".mp3" .Just out of curiosity, where does the extension come from, is it from the mime type or from the actual file name, and can Apache setting block it off?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean, but you could try to check what the 'client' receives by using Firefox with the Firbug addon. Just open Firebug and check what content headers are returned (hit F12 to open Firebug and check the 'Net' tab) -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11837707/stackoverflow/headers.jpg

Comment: well this is what i get, i am downloading a file that has the id of 19, from my database , it is the second request, and it downloads the file name 'enth nd..." https://www.dropbox.com/s/bpz1wx9gfl96sih/file%20type.png

Comment: Could you click on the '19' file and click the tabsheet 'headers'? I'm particularly interested in the response headers (they're at the bottom).

Comment: sorry net is very unstable, but here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/vrb7e8v0m4f4bxp/downloadfile.png  PS: thanks for persevering with me :)

Comment: No problem :) I think you should really check the value of $row[3], I'm almost certain it does not contain an extension. So either the extension is stored in another field or 'just' manually add .mp3 after $row[3] if you are certain it always is an mp3.
I can *assure* you this is the problem, as the response headers clearly indicate there is no extension.

Comment: it seems to work if i add the extension manually , if i take out the name, it automatically puts in the right extension...

Comment: That is probably because if you remove the 'Content-Disposition: attachment' header, the browser recognizes it as MP3 as that is specified in the 'Content-Type' header. So I would just add .mp3 to the extension and you are off to a new adventure ;)

Comment: Alright :) Could you mark the question as answered for people who have the same problem and end up here in the future? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding escaped quotes around the filename like this:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$row[3]\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Abit modification on Patrick answer

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="."\"{$fname}\"");
```